# PHP include slow takes 2.5 sec

Tags: php, performance, caching, include

I am displaying datatable using jQuery ajax. There is one file I include and it takes 2.5 sec first time. Kinda random. I could not figure out why it does that. Anyone have any clue?.

Running in my **local apache server in windows 7**. Is it because my pc doing something or my hard disk fragmented? I already defragment my harddisk..fragment is 0%. So something else? Anyone had this problem?

Issue is i have so many include before I get to that part of code. Those include never be this slow. I am using code igniter framework. It include many file. I even put full path to find why it creates the problem. No avail.

```
$time_start = microtime_float();

include $plugindir."/resources/queries/$queryname".".php";

$time_end = microtime_float();
echo "elapsed seconds1 $time_end  $time_start  : ".($time_end-$time_start). " seconds";
```

It is not all the time. First time mainly. Kinda weird.

Comment: Some code would be nice. I don't have my telepathy cap on and can't see what query is happening.

Comment: What is inside that file? Database calls? Inefficient code?

Comment: even empty file same issue. Because if you include inside a method it is doing that time instead of finding that file from cache.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating not actually *include* time, but include+execute time. So time it will takes strongly depends of what you're doing inside included file. Most likely you have some long-running database queries inside this file.
One more thing. Using `include $plugindir."/resources/queries/$queryname".".php";` is very unsafe if you do not check `$queryname` for any possible injection.

Comment: I kinda figured out but no solution yet. if the same include is above the class , no delay at all. If i have include in a method it speed is 100ms to 2.7sec varying. So either i need to include like 100 query php file in include in advance which gona eat up memory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xdebug, try to change this line in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
```

to this one:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=off
```

If you connect via localhost, use 127.0.0.1 instead, it seems to be a recurrent problem on [Windows 8](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,91602,page=3), but it's always worth a try!

Comment: The problem only happens if it is inside a method. I basically include different query file (which is generated query related data in a php ). Instead of loading 100s of queries ahead i thought i will include on demand..but it is creating a problem. If the same include in first line of the file then speed is instantenous because it is cached. if it is inside method its not cached for some reason between calls.